# Clean Swift - Routing without segues

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, architecture

I found `Router` in [Clean Swift](https://clean-swift.com/clean-swift-ios-architecture/) architecture is responsible to navigate and pass data between `view controllers.` Some samples and [articles](https://clean-swift.com/routing-in-clean-swift/) depict that `Routers` use segue to communicate with view controllers. What would be the convenient design when I don't want to use any segue from `Storyboard`. Is it possible to pass data without segue in Clean Swift? If you describe with simplest complete example, would be appreciated.

Comment: This repo will helps us for create Clean Swift Architecture files (Controller, Interactor, Presenter, Worker, Router and Models) easily -> https://github.com/emrcftci/clean-swift-architecture-file-template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Article says that you can:

> // 2. Present another view controller programmatically

You can use this to manually create, configure and push viewController.

Example.

Let's pretend that you have `ViewController` with button (handle push):

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var router: ViewControllerRouterInput!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        router = ViewControllerRouter(viewController: self)
    }

    @IBAction func pushController(_ sender: UIButton) {
        router.navigateToPushedViewController(value: 1)
    }

}
```

This `ViewController` has `router` that implements `ViewControllerRouterInput` protocol.

```
protocol ViewControllerRouterInput {
    func navigateToPushedViewController(value: Int)
}

final class ViewControllerRouter: ViewControllerRouterInput {

    weak var viewController: ViewController?

    init(viewController: ViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }

    // MARK: - ViewControllerRouterInput

    func navigateToPushedViewController(value: Int) {
        let pushedViewController = PushedViewController.instantiate()
        pushedViewController.configure(viewModel: PushedViewModel(value: value))
        viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(pushedViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

The `navigateToPushedViewController` func can takes any parameter you want (it is good to encapsulate parameters before configure new vc, so you may want to do that).

And the `PushedViewController` hasn't any specific implementation. Just `configure()` method and `assert` (notify you about missing `configure()` call):

```
final class PushedViewModel {

    let value: Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

}

final class PushedViewController: UIViewController, StoryboardBased {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    private var viewModel: PushedViewModel!

    func configure(viewModel: PushedViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        assert(viewModel != nil, "viewModel is nil. You should call configure method before push vc.")

        label.text = "Pushed View Controller with value: \(viewModel.value)"
    }

}
```

Note: also, i used [`Reusable`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable) pod to reduce boilerplate code.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As above article explained you can use option 2/3/4 of `navigateToSomewhere` method as per your app design.

```
func navigateToSomewhere()
  {

    // 2. Present another view controller programmatically
    // viewController.presentViewController(someWhereViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // 3. Ask the navigation controller to push another view controller onto the stack
    // viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(someWhereViewController, animated: true)

    // 4. Present a view controller from a different storyboard
    // let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "OtherThanMain", bundle: nil)
    // let someWhereViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! SomeWhereViewController
    // viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(someWhereViewController, animated: true)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need pass data across protocols

```
protocol SecondModuleInput {
    // pass data func or variable
    var data: Any? { get set }
}

protocol SecondModuleOutput {
    // pass data func or variable
    func send(data: Any)
}
```

First presenter

```
class FirstPresenter: SecondModuleOutput {

    var view: UIViewController

    var secondModuleInputHandler: SecondModuleInput?

    // MARK: SecondModuleInput
    func send(data: Any) {
        //sended data from SecondPresenter
    }
}
```

Second presenter

```
class SecondPresenter: SecondModuleInput {

    var view: UIViewController

    var secondModuleOutputHandler: SecondModuleOutput?

    static func configureWith(block: @escaping (SecondModuleInput) -> (SecondModuleOutput)) -> UIViewController {
        let secondPresenter = SecondPresenter()
        secondPresenter.secondModuleOutputHandler = block(secondPresenter)
        return secondPresenter.view
    }

    // Sending data to first presenter
    func sendDataToFirstPresenter(data: Any) {
        secondModuleOutputHandler?.send(data: data)
    }

    // MARK: FirstModuleInput
    var data: Any?
}
```

Router

```
class FirstRouter {

    func goToSecondModuleFrom(firstPresenter: FirstPresenter, with data: Any) {

        let secondPresenterView = SecondPresenter.configureWith { (secondPreseter) -> (SecondModuleOutput) in

            firstPresenter.secondModuleInputHandler = secondPreseter
            return firstPresenter
    }

        //Pass data to SecondPresenter
        firstPresenter.secondModuleInputHandler?.data = data

        //Go to another view controller
        //firstPresenter.view.present(secondPresenterView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //firstPresenter.view.navigationController.pushViewController(secondPresenterView, animated: true)
    }
}
```